# Can multiple SQL statements be executed in soci c++?

Tags: c++, sql

In soci (http://soci.sourceforge.net/), can you execute multiple SQL statements at once? E.g.:

```
session << "create table a(i integer); create table b(i integer)"
```

**UPDATE**: My purposes in the above feature is so that I can have a single file which contains multiple SQL statements for a particular version.

E.g.: `6.sql` contains the SQL to upgrade the database from version 5 to version 6.

```
alter table x add column y integer;
delete from z where c > 26;
update my_option_table set my_option_value = '6' where my_option_name = 'database_version';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does support bulk operations using loops haven't seen anything like multiple SQL statements being executed at once.

Bulk operations can be done using vectors as follows.

```
std::vector ids(BATCH_SIZE);

statement st = (sql.prepare <<
                "insert into numbers(value) values(:val)",
                use(ids));
```

For further details you may have a look at the following page.

[Bulk Operations](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/statements.html#bulk)

Comment: I'm not looking for bulk operations. I've clarified the question to reflect this.